# Copiar / clonar una hoja de Excel usando OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

Tengo una plantilla de Excel, la cual abro y voy rellenando algunos datos en celdas concretas. Una vez que tengo rellena esa hoja, según una variable que indica el número de copias, quiero clonar esa hoja que acabo de rellenar, X veces.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    private bool CrearExcel(Stream stream, DatosExcel datos)
        {
            bool ok = true;

            try
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {

                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;

                    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                    Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault();
                    sheet.Name = "Hoja";

                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart;
                    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                    WriteCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, sheetData, 1, 1, new CellValue(datos.dato1), new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String));
                    WriteCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, sheetData, 1, 2, new CellValue(datos.dato2), new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String));
                    WriteCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, sheetData, 1, 3, new CellValue(datos.dato3), new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String));

                    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                    if (datos.numerocopias > 1)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i < datos.numerocopias; i++)
                        {
                            SpreadsheetDocument tempSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(new MemoryStream(), spreadSheet.DocumentType);
                            WorkbookPart tempWorkbookPart = tempSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
                            WorksheetPart tempWorksheetPart = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart(worksheetPart);
                            WorksheetPart clonedSheet = workbookPart.AddPart(tempWorksheetPart);

                            sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                            Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet()
                            {
                                Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(clonedSheet),
                                SheetId = (UInt32)i + 1,
                                Name = "Hoja" + i.ToString()
                            };
                            sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
                            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                        }
                    }
                                       
                    spreadSheet.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ok = false;
            }
            return ok;
        }
```

Cuando abro el Excel, me ha creado la hoja nueva pero está vacía. No tiene ningún dato ni nada.